# java.nio.file.FileSystemException When moving files

Tags: java, pdfrenderer

I'm trying to create image from the last page of a pdf file using pdf-renderer. No problem with that.
But after creating the image, i want to move the original pdf file to a new folder, but always fail.

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\test.pdf -> D:\folder\test.pdf: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Here is my sample code:

```
    private String convertPDFtoImage(String myFile, String lokasiAwal, String lokasiBaru) {
    try {
        File pdfFile = new File(myFile);
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(pdfFile, "r");
        FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
        PDFFile pdf = new PDFFile(buf);
        Integer lastPage = pdf.getNumPages();
        PDFPage page = pdf.getPage(lastPage);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) page.getBBox().getWidth(), (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
        int width = rect.width;
        int height = rect.height;
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Image image = page.getImage(width, height, rect, null, true, true);
        Graphics2D bufImageGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        bufImageGraphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        String newImage = System.getProperty("user.home")+"/images/test.png";
        BufferedImage dest = bufferedImage.getSubimage(0, 0, width, height);
        ImageIO.write(dest, "png", new File(newImage));
        raf.close();
        Files.move(Paths.get(lokasiAwal), Paths.get(lokasiBaru));
        return newImage;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }
}
```

I think it's because the file is still being used by my app. I already tried raf.close() or channel.close() or both, no luck.
I have no idea what's locking my file.
How can i fix it?.

Comment: Since you are using jsr203, why don't you use it all the way? Why use File at all?

Comment: In the code you provided there is no clue what could be causing the problem since you use the `myFile` and you are trying to move `String lokasiAwal, String lokasiBaru` which is not used at all in your code. You problem may be before this method.

Comment: Please read on the community guide on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Titles like that are not really acceptable here.

Comment: Do you have test.pdf open in another application while you are trying to test this?  If so, try exiting that application first.

Comment: @JorgeCampos sorry, bad edit. String myFile is the same as String lokasiAwal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do the move outside the convertPDFtoImage method? This way it should be cleaner as raf, channel are both local to the method.